# angularjs. Display object property after http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to `Angular.js` and i did the tutorial `Shaping up with angularjs` in `codeschool.com` so please forgive me if the problem i am trying to solve might be too easy to resolve.

So, i am just trying to show a data i get from `$http.get()` which is `JSON` object into my document.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>League of legends</title>

    <!-- Load StyleSheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Load Javascript Libraries -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="LeagueOfLegends">
    <!-- Navbar menu -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="searchSummoner as summoner">
            <!-- Search Form -->
            <div ng-show="summoner.status.showSearch">
                <form ng-submit="summoner.search()">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="summonerName">Summoner Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Summoner Name" id="summonerName" ng-model="summoner.form.name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label ng-repeat="region in summoner.region">
                                <input type="radio" ng-model="summoner.form.region" ng-value="region">{{region}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search"></input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <p ng-show="summoner.status.showResult">Get request from: {{summoner.data.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

app.js (module-controller):

```
var app = angular.module('LeagueOfLegends', []);

app.controller('searchSummoner', ['$http', function($http)
{
    var form = {};
    this.data = {};

    this.form = {};
    this.status = {
        showSearch: true,
        showResult: false
    };

    this.region = ['br', 'eune', 'euw', 'lan', 'las', 'na', 'oce', 'kr', 'tr'];

    this.search = function()
    {
        form = this.form;

        this.form = {};

        // get data from the api rest
        $http.get(getApiUrl(form)).success(function(data){
            this.data = data[form.name];
            console.log(this.data);
        });

        // hide form
        this.status.showSearch = false;
        this.status.showResult = true;
    };
}]);

function getApiUrl(form)
{
    var apiKey = 'fe9eb24f-5800-4f2a-b570-15328062b341';

    return 'https://lan.api.pvp.net/api/lol/' + form.region + '/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' + form.name + '?api_key=fe9eb24f-5800-4f2a-b570-15328062b341'
}
```

after `$http.get` was successfully made, i make a log just to check if the data i retrieve is the one i need, but it does not show the object property in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `this` in the wrong closure. This is what you should do :

```
var that = this;//give controller scope access

// get data from the api rest
$http.get(getApiUrl(form)).success(function(data){
    that.data = data[form.name];
    console.log(that.data);
});
```

Comment: i don't quite understand it. but it seems like it works this way and i have to get use to it, i just don't see how declaring a variable named that with this value would do it

Comment: the `this` you were using was the one of the success callback function, not the one of your controller, so assigning `this.data = ...` inside the callback didn't endup in the data attribute of your controller

Comment: ow. i didn't know `this` was refering to the success callback function, thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

You could also bind your context like this:

```
$http.get(getApiUrl(form)).success(function(data){
    this.data = data[form.name];
    console.log(this.data);
}.bind(this));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind